# How to decrement a value in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I have a procedure that can find the `n` smallest primes larger than `from`

```
(define (primes_range from to n)
   (for ([i (in-range from to)])
        (if (> n 0)
            (cond ((prime? i) (display i)
                              (- n 1)))
            false)))
```

I add a parameter `n` to the procedure `primes_range` and decrement it during the execution only if a prime was found.
But `n` not changed. How to fix that?

Comment: `(- n 1)` is a number (specifically, it's i - 1), it does not modify the variable. I would recommend that you not try to directly translate programs from other languages but study Scheme instead.

Comment: Thanks, currently I solving SICP. Is it the good book?

Comment: It is an excellent book, one of the best, but you need to forget what you've learned in other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic Scheme way to write this function is to use recursion:

```
(define (primes-range from to n)
  (cond ((>= from to) '())
        ((<= n 0) '())
        ((prime? from) (cons from (primes-range (+ from 1) to (- n 1))))
        (else (primes-range (+ from 1) to n))))
```

You can easily spell this out in English:

- Base cases:

  1. A prime range where the `from` is equal or greater to `to` is empty.
  2. A prime range where `n` is 0 or less is empty.
- Recursive cases:

  1. If `from` is a prime, then the prime range is `from`, prepended to the result of calling `primes-range` starting from `(+ from 1)` and with `(- n 1)` elements.
  2. Otherwise, the result is calling `primes-range` starting from `(+ from 1)` (still with `n` elements).

Comment: Thank you very much! What does `'()` and `cons ` means?

Comment: I just read 50 pages of the SICP. So how can you solve this problem without  `'() and cons `

Comment: `(define (primes_range from to n) (filter prime? (iota from (- to from) 1))))`